# How to create the interactive print mehod (__repr__) for a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I am trying to create an object that contains a dictionary, and when I print the object, it prints the dictionary in the same way as when printing the dictionary in interactive mode.

See the example in ipython:

```py
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, d):
   ...:         self.d = d
   ...:
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return repr(self.d)

In [2]: a = {"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa": 1, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb": 2, "ccccccccccccccccccccccc": 3}

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
{'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 1,
 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 2,
 'ccccccccccccccccccccccc': 3}

In [4]: A(a)
Out[4]: {'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 1, 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 2, 'ccccccccccccccccccccccc': 3}
```

I would expect that printing `A(a)` would write every dictionary key in a different line, the same way than when we just print `a`, but this is not the case. How do I make this happen? I know I can manually create a method to print a dictionary how I like it, but I wonder if there is a way to do this without creating my own dictionary printing method to get the output, and just use the method that is used to print a dictionary in ipython.

Therefore, how do I get this?

```py
In [4]: A(a)
Out[4]:
{'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': 1,
 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 2,
 'ccccccccccccccccccccccc': 3}
```

Comment: That is a special aspect of `Ipython`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's interesting to know! Would it be possible to look into the implementation of Ipython to see how it is configured to display it this way?

Comment: They provide a hook: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html